# Python vs R for analzing spatial data

Tags: python, r, comparison, spatial-analysis

I am relatively new to both the python and R programming languages, having a small amount of exposure to both.  Which language has the edge when working with spatial data and when would you use R over python and vice versa?

Comment: In a nutshell: R has the edge without any doubt, when spatial statistics are needed. For other type of spatial analysis (e.g. computational geometry), big data, or when working with a GIS software (QGIS, GRASS, ArcGIS) is essential, python might be faster, and more extensive. Let's hope for a more detailed answer from one, who is more experienced with both of the languages. Also note, IMO this question can be flagged, as mainly opinion based, so extending it with a specific problem is recommended.

Comment: Why not both? Start using them both and when you feel confident you can combine them for some awesome kung-fu